# Subclass of C4Shape is not becoming a line with instance method

Tags: c4

I have created a subclass called Lines, that inherits from C4Shape. For now, all it does is create a random line when a class method is called.

The intention is that every new line begins at the previous line's `pointB` (i.e. end point) in order to make a continuing tree of lines. Eventually, I'll have multiple lines spawn from the same end point, old ones disappear, etc. Here's the code I have so far:

```
+(Lines *)createLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint {
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake([C4Math randomIntBetweenA:(startPoint.x-50) andB:(startPoint.x+50)],
                               [C4Math randomIntBetweenA:(startPoint.y-50) andB:(startPoint.y+50)]);
CGPoint linePoints[2] = {startPoint, endPoint};
Lines *newLine = [Lines new];
[newLine line:linePoints]; //This should make newLine a line type, should it not?
newLine.lineWidth = 3.0f;

return newLine;
}

-(void) setup {
[self performSelector:@selector(continueMakingLinesWithLine) withObject:(self) afterDelay:(3.0)];
}

-(void) continueMakingLinesWithLine {
[self.arrayOfLines addObject:[Lines createLineFromPoint:self.pointB]];
}
```

As far as I can tell, it should loop after the first call to `continueMakingLinesWithLine` in the C4WorkSpace; the first call is instantiated with a randomly generated CGPoint.

However, I am having a really hard time properly accessing the `pointB` property that was set during the last call to the method.

I received an error that tells me that it is because the C4Shape*(the Lines*) is not of type lines or arc.

However, the instance method should be making it of that type, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your actual error means. Your logic is quite correct though.

First things first, in your code you have the following:

```
[newLine line:linePoints]; //This should make newLine a line type, should it not?
```

The answer is `YES`, and it IS!

I copied your code into a new project and added each line to the canvas as it was created. The ran, albeit not the way I expected. *However, that's not your fault.*

You actually uncovered a small bug in the implementation of the [shapeObj line:...] method.

I will fix the bug in the C4iOS project on GitHub, however this won't appear in your project with the current installer you have.

### Workaround

You can do one of two things:

1) Return `C4Shape` from your lines subclass and initialize it using `[C4Shape line:linePoints]`

2) Add the following to `line 400` of `C4Shape.m`:

`if(CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectZero, self.frame)) { self.frame =
    lineRect; }`

For `1)` your method should look like:

```
+(Lines *)createLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint {
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake([C4Math randomIntBetweenA:.. andB:..],
                                   [C4Math randomIntBetweenA:.. andB:..]);
    CGPoint linePoints[2] = {startPoint, endPoint};
    C4Shape *newLine = [C4Shape line:linePoints];
    newLine.lineWidth = 3.0f;
    return (Lines *)newLine;
}
```

For `2)` the end of the method in `C4Shape.m` should look like:

```
-(void)_line:(NSArray *)pointArray {
    //Default implementation
    //..
    //..
    newBounds.origin = CGPointZero;
    if(CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectZero, self.frame)) { self.frame = lineRect; }
    CGPathRelease(newPath);
    _initialized = YES;
}
```

If you do `2)` you don't need to fix your current `+(Lines *)` method.

### Other Things

I tightened up the code you posted above to look like the following:

```
@interface C4WorkSpace ()
@property NSMutableArray *arrayOfLines;
@end

@implementation C4WorkSpace

-(void) setup {
    self.arrayOfLines = [@[] mutableCopy];
    Lines *newLine = [Lines createLineFromPoint:self.canvas.center];
    [self.arrayOfLines addObject:newLine];
    [self.canvas addShape:newLine];
    [self continueMakingLinesWithLine];
}

-(void) continueMakingLinesWithLine {
    CGPoint p = ((Lines *)[self.arrayOfLines lastObject]).pointB;
    Lines *newLine = [Lines createLineFromPoint:p];
    [self.arrayOfLines addObject:newLine];
    [self.canvas addShape:newLine];
    [self runMethod:@"continueMakingLinesWithLine" afterDelay:1.0f];
}
@end
```

In `setup` I create the first line and add it to the canvas AND the array. Then, I let the `continueMakingLinesWithLine` method find the previous line, build a new one and then call itself again.